# Dumping JSON into MySQL using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, api, json.net

I have read dozens of articles, tutorials, and answers, but it's just not clicking for me.  I'm new to APIs and JSON, with beginner to intermediate .NET skills.  I need to retrieve data from a Survey API and dump it into a MySQL database.  Getting the data is no problem, but once I get it, I have no idea what to do with it.  I know I'll have to loop through the JSON, but I can't seem to get there.  Would somebody please explain to me how to dig down into the results and pick out each data point?  I can figure out from there how to dump it into the database.  I have updated my code to reflect my latest efforts.
Here are my classes I created using QuickType.io:

```
    namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using J = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute;

    public partial class Survey
    {
        [J("result_ok")] public bool ResultOk { get; set; }
        [J("total_count")] public string TotalCount { get; set; }
        [J("page")] public long Page { get; set; }
        [J("total_pages")] public long TotalPages { get; set; }
        [J("results_per_page")] public long ResultsPerPage { get; set; }
        [J("data")] public Datum[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Datum
    {
        [J("id")] public string Id { get; set; }
        [J("contact_id")] public string ContactId { get; set; }
        [J("status")] public string Status { get; set; }
        [J("is_test_data")] public string IsTestData { get; set; }
        [J("datesubmitted")] public DateTime Datesubmitted { get; set; }
        [J("SessionID")] public string SessionId { get; set; }
        [J("Language")] public string Language { get; set; }
        [J("datestarted")] public DateTime Datestarted { get; set; }
        [J("iLinkID")] public string ILinkId { get; set; }
        [J("sResponseComment")] public string SResponseComment { get; set; }
        [J("responseID")] public string ResponseId { get; set; }
        [J("[question(5)]")] public string Question5 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(7)]")] public string Question7 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(11)]")] public string Question11 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(12)]")] public string Question12 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(13)]")] public string Question13 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(15)]")] public string Question15 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(17)]")] public string Question17 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(27)]")] public string Question27 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(29)]")] public string Question29 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(35)]")] public string Question35 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(36)]")] public string Question36 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(42)]")] public string Question42 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(43)]")] public string Question43 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(44)]")] public string Question44 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(46)]")] public string Question46 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(51)]")] public string Question51 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(53)]")] public string Question53 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(55)]")] public string Question55 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(57)]")] public string Question57 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(91)]")] public string Question91 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(94)]")] public string Question94 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(97)]")] public string Question97 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(98)]")] public string Question98 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(99)]")] public string Question99 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(100)]")] public string Question100 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(102)]")] public string Question102 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(105)]")] public string Question105 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(106)]")] public string Question106 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(109)]")] public string Question109 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(110)]")] public string Question110 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(111)]")] public string Question111 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(112)]")] public string Question112 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(113)]")] public string Question113 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(114)]")] public string Question114 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(115)]")] public string Question115 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(116)]")] public string Question116 { get; set; }
        [J("[question(117)]")] public string Question117 { get; set; }
        [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_IP\")]")] public string VariableStandardIp 

{ get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_LONG\")]")] public string VariableStandardLong { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_LAT\")]")] public string VariableStandardLat { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCOUNTRY\")]")] public string VariableStandardGeocountry { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOCITY\")]")] public string VariableStandardGeocity { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOREGION\")]")] public string VariableStandardGeoregion { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_GEOPOSTAL\")]")] public string VariableStandardGeopostal { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_RESPONSETIME\")]")] public string VariableStandardResponsetime { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_COMMENTS\")]")] public string VariableStandardComments { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_DEVICE\")]")] public string VariableStandardDevice { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_DATAQUALITYCOUNTER\")]")] public string VariableStandardDataqualitycounter { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_CHECKBOXONE_COUNT\")]")] public string VariableStandardCheckboxoneCount { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_CHECKBOXONE\")]")] public string VariableStandardCheckboxone { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_STRAIGHTLINING_COUNT\")]")] public string VariableStandardStraightliningCount { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_STRAIGHTLINING\")]")] public string VariableStandardStraightlining { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_OPENTEXTGIBBERISH_COUNT\")]")] public string VariableStandardOpentextgibberishCount { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_OPENTEXTGIBBERISH\")]")] public string VariableStandardOpentextgibberish { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_OPENTEXTBADWORDS_COUNT\")]")] public string VariableStandardOpentextbadwordsCount { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_OPENTEXTBADWORDS\")]")] public string VariableStandardOpentextbadwords { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_OPENTEXTONEWORDREQUIREDESSAY_COUNT\")]")] public string VariableStandardOpentextonewordrequiredessayCount { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_OPENTEXTONEWORDREQUIREDESSAY\")]")] public string VariableStandardOpentextonewordrequiredessay { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_CHECKBOXALL_COUNT\")]")] public string VariableStandardCheckboxallCount { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_CHECKBOXALL\")]")] public string VariableStandardCheckboxall { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_AVGQUESTSECONDS\")]")] public string VariableStandardAvgquestseconds { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_FINGERPRINT\")]")] public string VariableStandardFingerprint { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_GEODMA\")]")] public string VariableStandardGeodma { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_REFERER\")]")] public string VariableStandardReferer { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"STANDARD_USERAGENT\")]")] public string VariableStandardUseragent { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"PORTAL_RELATIONSHIP\")]")] public string VariablePortalRelationship { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"1-shown\")]")] public string Variable1Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"4-shown\")]")] public string Variable4Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"5-shown\")]")] public string Variable5Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(5)]")] public string Variable5 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"7-shown\")]")] public string Variable7Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"11-shown\")]")] public string Variable11Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(11)]")] public string Variable11 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"13-shown\")]")] public string Variable13Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(13)]")] public string Variable13 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"14-shown\")]")] public string Variable14Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"15-shown\")]")] public string Variable15Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(15)]")] public string Variable15 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"17-shown\")]")] public string Variable17Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(27)]")] public string Variable27 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"27-shown\")]")] public string Variable27Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(29)]")] public string Variable29 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"29-shown\")]")] public string Variable29Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"34-shown\")]")] public string Variable34Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(35)]")] public string Variable35 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"35-shown\")]")] public string Variable35Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(36)]")] public string Variable36 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"36-shown\")]")] public string Variable36Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"42-shown\")]")] public string Variable42Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(42)]")] public string Variable42 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"44-shown\")]")] public string Variable44Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"46-shown\")]")] public string Variable46Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(46)]")] public string Variable46 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"51-shown\")]")] public string Variable51Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(51)]")] public string Variable51 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(53)]")] public string Variable53 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"53-shown\")]")] public string Variable53Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"55-shown\")]")] public string Variable55Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"56-shown\")]")] public string Variable56Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"57-shown\")]")] public string Variable57Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"91-shown\")]")] public string Variable91Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(91)]")] public string Variable91 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"93-shown\")]")] public string Variable93Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"94-shown\")]")] public string Variable94Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"97-shown\")]")] public string Variable97Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"98-shown\")]")] public string Variable98Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"99-shown\")]")] public string Variable99Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"100-shown\")]")] public string Variable100Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"101-shown\")]")] public string Variable101Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"102-shown\")]")] public string Variable102Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(102)]")] public string Variable102 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"105-shown\")]")] public string Variable105Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(105)]")] public string Variable105 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"106-shown\")]")] public string Variable106Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(106)]")] public string Variable106 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"108-shown\")]")] public string Variable108Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(109)]")] public string Variable109 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"109-shown\")]")] public string Variable109Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(110)]")] public string Variable110 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"110-shown\")]")] public string Variable110Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(111)]")] public string Variable111 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"111-shown\")]")] public string Variable111Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(112)]")] public string Variable112 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"112-shown\")]")] public string Variable112Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(113)]")] public string Variable113 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"113-shown\")]")] public string Variable113Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(114)]")] public string Variable114 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"114-shown\")]")] public string Variable114Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(115)]")] public string Variable115 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"115-shown\")]")] public string Variable115Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(116)]")] public string Variable116 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"116-shown\")]")] public string Variable116Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(117)]")] public string Variable117 { get; set; }
            [J("[variable(\"117-shown\")]")] public string Variable117Shown { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(5)]")] public string Comment5 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(11)]")] public string Comment11 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(13)]")] public string Comment13 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(15)]")] public string Comment15 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(27)]")] public string Comment27 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(29)]")] public string Comment29 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(35)]")] public string Comment35 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(36)]")] public string Comment36 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(42)]")] public string Comment42 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(46)]")] public string Comment46 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(51)]")] public string Comment51 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(53)]")] public string Comment53 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(102)]")] public string Comment102 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(105)]")] public string Comment105 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(106)]")] public string Comment106 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(109)]")] public string Comment109 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(110)]")] public string Comment110 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(111)]")] public string Comment111 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(112)]")] public string Comment112 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(113)]")] public string Comment113 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(114)]")] public string Comment114 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(115)]")] public string Comment115 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(116)]")] public string Comment116 { get; set; }
            [J("[comment(117)]")] public string Comment117 { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Survey
        {
            public static Survey FromJson(string json)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Survey>(json, Converter.Settings);
            }
        }
    public partial class Datum
{


public static Datum FromJson(string json )
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }
}


        public static class Serialize
        {
            public static string ToJson(this Survey self)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
            }
        }



        public class Converter
        {
            public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            };
        }
    }
```

Here's a partial representation of the data being retrieved:

```
    Array
(
    [result_ok] => 1
    [total_count] => 54
    [page] => 1
    [total_pages] => 1
    [results_per_page] => 500
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [contact_id] => 
                    [status] => Complete
                    [is_test_data] => 0
                    [datesubmitted] => 2017-09-12 14:12:21
                    [SessionID] => 1505238728_59b81ec88b2337.99042127
                    [Language] => English
                    [datestarted] => 2017-09-12 14:08:05
                    [iLinkID] => 5730460
                    [sResponseComment] => 
                    [responseID] => 8
                    [[question(5)]] => Strongly agree
                    [[question(7)]] => 
                    [[question(11)]] => Strongly agree
                    [[question(12)]] => 
                    [[question(13)]] => 0
                    [[question(15)]] => Disagree
                    [[question(17)]] => There should be more clarity on the initial process. It seemed as if we were going in many directions at times. I would strongly recommend a daily checklist, that in the end, would be a reference guide to the daily operations after training is completed. 
                    [[question(27)]] => 0
                    [[question(29)]] => 
                    [[question(35)]] => Prepared
                    [[question(36)]] => Prepared
                    [[question(42)]] => 
                    [[question(43)]] => 
                    [[question(44)]] => 
                    [[question(46)]] => About right
                    [[question(51)]] => A little fast
                    [[question(53)]] => 100
                    [[question(55)]] => 
                    [[question(57)]] => some text here
                    [[question(91)]] => Person's Name
                    [[question(94)]] => 2017/08/14
                    [[question(97)]] => 
                    [[question(98)]] => 
                    [[question(99)]] => 
                    [[question(100)]] => 
                    [[question(102)]] => About right
                    [[question(105)]] => 
                    [[question(106)]] => 
                    [[question(109)]] => 
                    [[question(110)]] => 
                    [[question(111)]] => Very Prepared
                    [[question(112)]] => 
                    [[question(113)]] => 
                    [[question(114)]] => 
                    [[question(115)]] => Strongly agree
                    [[question(116)]] => 
                    [[question(117)]] => 100
                    [[variable("STANDARD_IP")]] => 96.63.68.4
                    [[variable("STANDARD_LONG")]] => -86.784400939941
                    [[variable("STANDARD_LAT")]] => 36.165901184082
                    [[variable("STANDARD_GEOCOUNTRY")]] => United States
                    [[variable("STANDARD_GEOCITY")]] => Nashville
                    [[variable("STANDARD_GEOREGION")]] => TN
                    [[variable("STANDARD_GEOPOSTAL")]] => 37222
                    [[variable("STANDARD_RESPONSETIME")]] => 324
                    [[variable("STANDARD_COMMENTS")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_DEVICE")]] => Desktop
                    [[variable("STANDARD_DATAQUALITYCOUNTER")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_CHECKBOXONE_COUNT")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_CHECKBOXONE")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_STRAIGHTLINING_COUNT")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_STRAIGHTLINING")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_OPENTEXTGIBBERISH_COUNT")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_OPENTEXTGIBBERISH")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_OPENTEXTBADWORDS_COUNT")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_OPENTEXTBADWORDS")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_OPENTEXTONEWORDREQUIREDESSAY_COUNT")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_OPENTEXTONEWORDREQUIREDESSAY")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_CHECKBOXALL_COUNT")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_CHECKBOXALL")]] => 
                    [[variable("STANDARD_AVGQUESTSECONDS")]] => 46.4
                    [[variable("STANDARD_FINGERPRINT")]] => 3190959233
                    [[variable("STANDARD_GEODMA")]] => 659
                    [[variable("STANDARD_REFERER")]] => http://www.URL.com/s3/3793208/SurveyName-2-0
                    [[variable("STANDARD_USERAGENT")]] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
                    [[variable("PORTAL_RELATIONSHIP")]] => 
                    [[variable("1-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("4-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("5-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(5)]] => 10005
                    [[variable("7-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable("11-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(11)]] => 10011
                    [[variable("13-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(13)]] => 10015
                    [[variable("14-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("15-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(15)]] => 10020
                    [[variable("17-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(27)]] => 10045
                    [[variable("27-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(29)]] => 
                    [[variable("29-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable("34-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(35)]] => 10061
                    [[variable("35-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(36)]] => 10064
                    [[variable("36-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("42-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(42)]] => 
                    [[variable("44-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable("46-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(46)]] => 10084
                    [[variable("51-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(51)]] => 10124
                    [[variable(53)]] => 10106
                    [[variable("53-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("55-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("56-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("57-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("91-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(91)]] => 10214
                    [[variable("93-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("94-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("97-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable("98-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable("99-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable("100-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable("101-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable("102-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(102)]] => 10232
                    [[variable("105-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(105)]] => 
                    [[variable("106-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(106)]] => 
                    [[variable("108-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(109)]] => 
                    [[variable("109-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(110)]] => 
                    [[variable("110-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(111)]] => 10267
                    [[variable("111-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(112)]] => 
                    [[variable("112-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(113)]] => 
                    [[variable("113-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(114)]] => 
                    [[variable("114-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(115)]] => 10287
                    [[variable("115-shown")]] => 1
                    [[variable(116)]] => 
                    [[variable("116-shown")]] => 
                    [[variable(117)]] => 10297
                    [[variable("117-shown")]] => 1
                    [[comment(5)]] => 
                    [[comment(11)]] => 
                    [[comment(13)]] => 
                    [[comment(15)]] => Some text here
                    [[comment(27)]] => 
                    [[comment(29)]] => 
                    [[comment(35)]] => 
                    [[comment(36)]] => 
                    [[comment(42)]] => 
                    [[comment(46)]] => 
                    [[comment(51)]] => Some text here
                    [[comment(53)]] => 
                    [[comment(102)]] => 
                    [[comment(105)]] => 
                    [[comment(106)]] => 
                    [[comment(109)]] => 
                    [[comment(110)]] => 
                    [[comment(111)]] => 
                    [[comment(112)]] => 
                    [[comment(113)]] => 
                    [[comment(114)]] => 
                    [[comment(115)]] => 
                    [[comment(116)]] => 
                    [[comment(117)]] => 
                )
```

And here's what I've come up with so far.  When I debug, I get an error message saying Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: Q. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
I have validated the JSON at JSONLint.com, and it says it's valid JSON.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using QuickType;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;


public partial class dashboard_jsosn4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var myWebClient = new WebClient();
         string strURL = "http://restapi.URLHere.json?api_token=token&api_token_secret=secret&resultsperpage=1000&filter[field][0]=datesubmitted&filter[operator][0]=%3E=&filter[value][0]=2017-08-21&filter[field][3]=datesubmitted&filter[operator][3]=%3C&filter[value][3]=2018-01-08&filter[field][1]=status&filter[operator][1]==&filter[value][1]=Complete";
         string getSurveyResponses = myWebClient.DownloadString(strURL);
        Datum datum = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>(getSurveyResponses.ToString());`

       JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(datum.ToString()));

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Value != null)
        {
            Response.Write(reader.Value);

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Null");
        }
    }
    Response.Write("Done");

}



    }
```